# Fix holes in overlapping curves (Text)?

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object

Blender seems to subtract overlapping curves instead of filling them the way letters are usually displayed. Is there a way to fill them without converting them to mesh or seperating them ? I need these seperate so I can animate them. Sometimes the curves are not closed and different shapes but it's where the same curve intersects itself, creating a hole.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sadly curve filling options in Blender are limited in terms of options and there is little one can do other than separate into different objects.

One potential workaround is to assign different material slots to each spline. If splines have different Material IDs Blender won't try to fill them as a single area.

Just select one of the splines, add a new material slot from the *Properties Window > Materials* tabs, and assign it to only one of the overlapping splines. They may still have the same material applied, only need to be on different slots.

[image]

Beware that this a workaround and doesn't always work reliably, it may fail under certain situations.

Comment: This is genius, thank you so much! I added another image to the question, this workaraound unfortunately only works with two closed shapes in the curve object. When the curve intersects itself holes appear too. I'll check if this is neglectable, your answer already helped a lot!

Comment: I can only imagine how long you had to smash your head against a wall before you found this workaround :)). Nice one.

Comment: @jachym I think I found it by accident, much like I found by chance in some answer here that you could assign different materials to each spline